# How to update the attribute value for dynamic JSON file using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, npm, node-modules

I'm checking if the input.json file key matches in the server.json file then update the value of server.json file. The problem is server.json file is dynamic json file and the structure is not able predicted and it contains 100 elements with nested array and complex format. I just want to check the input.json key is available anywhere in the server.json (dynamic content) file

I have below json input file with some attribute and values:

**input.json:**

```
{"country":"GB","currency":"GBP"}
```

**Sample server.json (Dynamic content unpredictable):**

```
{
    "bank": [    
        {

        "country":"US",
        "currency":"USD"
       
        }
    ]
    
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "bank": [    
        {
       
        "country":"GB",
        "currency":"GBP",
      
        }
    ]
    
}
```

I just want to update the above server.json file values from input.json file if the key matches. And both (Input.json, and server.json ) files should have same key (country,currency).But the problem is the index of key in server.json is unknown, and it will be dynamic content.

User might give any input which is available in the server.json and based on key matching it needs to updated.

**Tried below sample:**

```
async function generateRequestBody(actual, index, functionRef) {
    let callback;
    let payload;
    _globaldeclartion = actual;
    Object.keys(dataset[index]).forEach(function (queueId) {
        if (queueId == functionRef) {
            payload = dataset[index][queueId];
            return;
        }
    });
    payload = await jsonValidator(payload);
    await updateJsonFile(_globaldeclartion, async (data) => {
        Object.keys(data).forEach(async (T) => {
            console.log(T);
            data[T] = payload[T];
        });
        callback = data;
        return data;
    });
    return callback;
```

I just want to update the server.json if the input.json file key matches with server.json (un predictable json structure) file.

**Updated:**

sometime the **server.js** file will be followed structured:

```
 {
           
            "country":"GB",
            "currency":"GBP",
          
   }
```

and sometimes it may have few more nested array.

```
    {
   "bank":[
      {
         "property":[
            {
               "country":"GB",
               "currency":"GBP"
            }
         ],
        
      }
   ]
}
```

and the server.json structrue is unpredictable and we need to check only the input.json key is availble in the server.json and need to change those values irrespective of structure.

**Updated - Latest:**

```
async function getIdea(input, data)
{
    var datastring = JSON.stringify(data);
    Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        console.log(key);
        console.log(value);
        var re = new RegExp(`"${key}":"[^"]*"`, "g");
        console.log(re);
        dataString = datastring.replace(re, `"${key}":"${value}"`);
    });

    console.log(JSON.parse(datastring))
}
```

getIdea(input, data);

**Input.json**

```
{
    "country":"GB",
    "currency":"GBP"
}
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "bank": [    
        {
       
        "country":"US",
        "currency":"USD",
       
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output Console:**

```
country
GB
/"country":"[^"]*"/g 
currency
GBP
/"currency":"[^"]*"/g
{
  bank: [
    {
    
      country: 'US',
      currency: 'USD',
      
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

There are many ways how to do this.

You can simply stringify the object you need to modify and go through the entries of input object, using regex to replace what is needed.

```
var updateProps = function(data, input) {

  var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);

  // Iterate over all entries in input object
  Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, value]) => {

    // matches property value string pair you are looking for 
    // eg.: "country": "US"
    var re = new RegExp(`"${key}":"[^"]*"`, "g");

    // replace what with new pair
    dataString = dataString.replace(re, `"${key}":"${value}"`)
    
  });

  return JSON.parse(dataString)
}
```

Now you just call the function on the objects needed:

```
var input = {
  "country": "GB",
  "currency": "GBP"
}

var server1 = {
  "bank": [{
    "bankAccountType": "Saving",
    "country": "US",
    "currency": "USD",
    "firstName": "TestFirstName",
    "lastName": "TestLastName",
    "confirmed": "true"
  }]
}

var server2 = {
  "bankAccountType": "Saving",
  "country": "GB",
  "currency": "GBP",
  "firstName": "TestFirstName",
  "lastName": "TestLastName",
  "confirmed": "true"
}


console.log("Changed object 1: ", fn(server1, input))
console.log("Changed object 2: ", fn(server2, input))
/* 
 {...,"country":"US","currency":"USD",...}
  chagnes to:
 {...,"country":"GB","currency":"GBP",...}
*/
```

Comment: Many thanks for sharing the steps. Let me check this out...! You saved my time...!!! Thanks once again.!